# using @Html.ActionLink with @Html raw

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

> item.Titel contains tags like paragraph/bold/italian tag, So i need to use
>   @html.Raw(item.Titel) for following code
>
> working code

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "AuthorByTocpicID", "AV", new { _Article_Id = item.Article_ID.ToString(),Title=item.Title}, null)
```

> error code need update/edit

```
@Html.ActionLink(@html.Raw(item.Title), "AuthorByTocpicID", "AV", new { 
_Article_Id = item.Article_ID.ToString(),Title=@html.Raw(item.Title)}, null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an Actionlink, construct the link yourself and use Url.Action . You have more control this way and you can use Html.Raw for the display text.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("AuthorByTocpicID","AV", new { _Article_Id = item.Article_ID.ToString(),Title=item.Title})">
       @Html.Raw(item.Title)
</a>
```

See below overloaded method used here for Url.Action

```
public static string Action(this IUrlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object values);
```